# Second derivative and chain rule

Tags: calculus

My professor did a differentiation in class and I don't see how he got this:

$$x=e^t \Rightarrow t=\ln(x) \Rightarrow \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac1x$$

$$\frac{dV}{dx} = \frac{dV}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac1x\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}$$

$$\frac{d^2V}{dx^2}=-\frac1{x^2}\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}+\frac1{x^2}\cdot\frac{d^2V}{dt^2}$$

Comment: I made an edit based on what you had written:  please check whether I rewrote everything correctly.

Comment: Which step didn't you understand ?

Comment: Taking the second derivative

Comment: So the second part should be 1/x rather than 1/x^2?

Comment: He merely used the chain rule for the second derivative.

Comment: I know but I don't see how.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that $$\frac{dV}{dx}=\frac1x\frac{dV}{dt},$$ to find the second derivative $$\frac{d^2V}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dV}{dx},$$ you just apply the product rule, to get $$\left(\frac1x\right)'\frac{dV}{dt}+\frac1x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dV}{dt}\right),$$ where you use the chain rule on the derivative in the last term to get $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dV}{dt}=\left(\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dV}{dt}\right)\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac1x\frac{d^2V}{dt^2}.$$

Comment: What program are you using to type your equations?

Comment: @Fringe_Agent13 Just MathJax -- same way you typed yours.